# Does pushing a string into an array, or setting it as the value to an object property, copy the string or keep a reference in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, v8

In v8 / Node.js in particular, when you push a *primitive type* (string, number, boolean) into an array, does it *clone* the string, or store a reference?

I know you can't do this and change the string:

```
let array = []
let x = 'foo'
array.push(x)
x = 'bar'
console.log(array) //=> ['foo']
```

But if I do this, is it copying the string multiple times (thereby increasing the memory footprint)?

```
let array = []
let x = 'foo'
array.push(x)
array.push(x)
array.push(x)
...
```

Same question for object keys, if I do this will it clone the string?

```
let object = {}
let x = 'foo'
object.a = x
object.b = x
object.c = x
```

I searched around a bit but didn't find a direct answer to this question.

[Do objects pushed into an array in javascript deep or shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660901/do-objects-pushed-into-an-array-in-javascript-deep-or-shallow-copy)

[This blog post](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/array-push-in-javascript-is-it-deep-or-shallow-copy-90cd195ec5b7#:%7E:text=Objects%20and%20arrays%20are%20pushed,are%20pushed%20as%20a%20copy.&text=y%20points%20to%20new%20reference,array%20value%20will%20not%20change.) says:

> Objects and arrays are pushed as a pointer to the original object. **Built-in primitive types like numbers or booleans are pushed as a copy.**

But I'm not sure if that is correct (it is not backed up). I would have to run a bunch of thorough tests to really check and see if memory grows when I push into an array or not. I'm not quite sure the easiest way to accomplish that, so perhaps a v8 engineer or someone else well-versed in the compiler theory knows how this is implemented.

I want to use `Buffer.byteLength(text, 'utf8')` to calculate the size of each string I am adding to a trie, and then keep track of the rough size of the trie (summing the string sizes used in it, and rough guestimating the bytes used to store n number of object properties and x-length arrays). So first step is understanding, *will my string get copied when I push it into multiple places, or will the same reference be carried around in each place?*

I would hope that blog is incorrect and that it pushes a reference, it's just that you can't modify a *variable* once it's been sent to another function. But the string is still a reference, until you try and change the variable, something like that.

Comment: The js value is cloned, since it's a primitive. The underlying representation typically is a reference to the bytes of text though, and only that reference needs to be copied, since the referenced bytes never change.

Comment: @Bergi The key point is that the string is *not* cloned. I don't think the duped question answers that at all. Wanna reopen this so I can post my answer?

Comment: @jmrk huh, you're right, it's not stated explicitly in [any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68789144/how-much-memory-do-v8-take-to-store-a-string) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40512393/understanding-string-heap-size-in-javascript-v8) [those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61627573/do-browsers-always-treat-strings-and-numbers-in-javascript-as-immutable) (though imo it's strongly implied/can be easily inferred). Feel free to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

When storing a string in an array (or anywhere, really), the string is not copied. Neither are booleans.

For numbers, it depends: they are usually also stored as references, except for [certain optimized cases](https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds) where there are more efficient alternatives.

The reason is twofold:
(1) There is no need to clone strings.
(2) It is simpler and faster not to clone strings.

The snippet you quoted is plain wrong as far as implementation details are concerned. One could argue that it is not entirely incorrect as far as observable semantics are concerned: your program's behavior cannot tell whether a copy of the string was stored, or just another reference to it. (But of course that just makes the whole statement meaningless: if objects are stored as references, and for primitives we cannot tell the difference, why not simply assume that everything is stored as reference?)

As a rule of thumb: VMs for dynamic languages like JavaScript treat everything as a reference, except for whichever special cases they choose to optimize (typically some definition of number; search for the terms "smi-tagging" and "nan-boxing" if you want to dig deeper).
Whether a value is a "primitive" or not only affects whether it has object identity:

```
{foo: 42} === {foo: 42}  // false, objects have identity
42 === 42                // true, numbers have no identity
"foo" === "foo"          // true, strings have no identity
```

Being a primitive does not affect how a value is stored in arrays/objects/variables/whatever, nor where it is allocated (a related myth I sometimes see is "primitives are allocated on the stack" -- nope, they are not).

---

**Added** clarification on @Bergi's request:
Of course, when you repeatedly call `array.push(x)`, the size of the array's backing stores grows, because it needs to store increasingly many references to the string. So while the string won't be copied, overall memory usage will increase (on average by one pointer per push, but actually happening in chunks).

Comment: "*The snippet you quoted is plain wrong as far as implementation details are concerned*" - well that blog article is not concerned with implementation details, it tries to explain the difference between primitive and reference values (objects) to beginners.

Comment: "*the string is not copied. Neither are booleans.*" - you might first want to qualify what exactly you mean by "string" or "boolean". There must be something that will be copied to stored it in the array/object.

Comment: @Bergi _"it tries to explain the difference between primitive and reference values"_ Well, I don't think it does a good job of that. Even "primitives don't have properties" would arguably be a more meaningful characterization. _"There must be something that will be copied"_ Yes, a reference to the thing (no matter whether "the thing" is a boolean or a string or an object). `a[0] = foo` and `var x = foo` are very similar: `x` and `a[0]` will afterwards hold a reference to whatever value `foo` is also referencing. That value could be an object, or an immutable primitive.

Comment: Please add that to your answer - the array/object will grow by the size of the reference when the new property is added. Btw, do you not consider the reference to *be* the value? I usually refer to the "referenced thing" as the "contents of the value". But maybe that's just the JS perspective not the engine perspective.

Comment: @Bergi: _"do you not consider the reference to be the value?"_ No, I don't. Of course, references are a particular kind of value, but distinguishing concepts like "pass by reference" and "pass by value" only makes sense when you don't equate values and references. I'll happily agree that "value" is an overloaded term though, and is commonly used for different concepts, e.g. depending on the abstraction level of the statement in question :-)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript VMs will never copy strings if they can avoid it. In this case, it's trivial to not copy the string.

If you truly wish to copy strings, you need to go through shenanigans, such as converting them to other encodings and back or splitting them and concatenating them back. If my memory serves correctly, last time I checked, once strings were copied, VMs didn't try to deduplicate them.

Source: Used to work on SpiderMonkey.